# How to generate CSRF token in Reactjs and send to Play Framework?

Tags: reactjs, scala, post, playframework, csrf

I was trying to send a post request from react form to play framework. It is throwing the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No CSRF token was generated for this request! Is the CSRF filter installed?
```

While using Play templates, CSRF token is handled from the template itself. Since I'm trying to use React for front end, I cannot use Play templates. Can anyone guide me on generating CSRF token in React and passing it to Play?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you can set up an action to generate a CSRF token (see [docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaCsrf#Getting-the-current-token)):

> If you are not using the CSRF filter, you also should inject the CSRFAddToken and CSRFCheck action wrappers to force adding a token or a CSRF check on a specific action. Otherwise the token will not be available.

```
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.mvc.Results._
import play.filters.csrf._
import play.filters.csrf.CSRF.Token

class CSRFController(components: ControllerComponents, addToken: CSRFAddToken, checkToken: CSRFCheck) extends AbstractController(components) {
  def getToken = addToken(Action { implicit request =>
    val Token(name, value) = CSRF.getToken.get
    Ok(s"$name=$value")
  })
}
```

GET this and pass it to the React form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrfToken" value="1234567890abcdef"/>
```

(or add it directly to the POST request.)

Comment: I may be wrong. Please correct me. AFAIK this is sending the csrf token to the client, right?Now the client should be able to read the token and send it back to the server along with the request. As there won't be any communication between server and client until the form is posted, how will this work. I'm sorry if I sound dumb. Hoping for some clear explanation

Comment: Yes. You'd GET the token before posting, potentially immediately before (doing two requests sequentially onclick). "As there won't be any communication between server and client until the form is posted" there will be, the GET has to happen before the POST.

Comment: Actually I'm serving the form in the front-end server with react and the communication only happens while sending post request. Shall I retrieve the csrf token before posting the form or is their any other standard approach?

Comment: I think this is how you have to do it, you have to change the logic in your react app. Either do in JavaScript as two calls when they submit, or fetch as as a hidden input initially.