# CSRF Tokens without server side rendering

Tags: security, csrf

I am looking for a way to prevent CSRF attacks, but am confused about how to pass the CSRF token to the client. I would like to avoid inserting the token into the HTML because I want to minimize server side render and opt for statically served pages instead. For authentication, sessions with cookies are being used.

So how does one get the CSRF token to the client then? I read about the [double posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50732159/how-to-pass-csrf-token-from-server-to-client) strategy, but read it was less secure than inserting the token into the html server side. Could an alternative be sending a separate authenticated GET request to the server after the page is served to request a CSRF token? The server then stores the CSRF token in the user's session and sends it back to the client.

Sorry if this is a silly question, but I want to be sure :)